# Bluetooth Mouse not detected after a reboot

Tags: windows-7, mouse, bluetooth, connection

When I couple my Bluetooth Mouse, it works fine, even when I put my laptop to sleep and wake it.

When I reboot my laptop, my Bluetooth Mouse is listed in Devices and Printers but does not function.
I need to remove the device and couple it again, this is annoying to do everytime I boot...

[My Mouse](http://www.trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=15352)
[My Laptop Specs](http://speccy.piriform.com/results/89OEAETnhrdkI3861OaFWSt), it has a CSR Bluetooth PLC built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Microsoft Support article might help: [Resolve Bluetooth mouse or keyboard failure to function](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811798).

The article contains 6 possible fixes or tests. Even if none of them helps, of special interest is the section named "Method 4: Locate the Wireless Link icon in Control Panel, and then reestablish the link with the wireless device".

It would help if you could report on what you saw when following this Method 4, maybe even adding screenshots for specially interesting info.

Comment: For Method 4 it says it's "Currently Connected"... :-S

Comment: I have once tried BlueSoleil to resolve this problem and it didn't have the problem with BlueSoleil as far as I know, but as that is only a Trial I'm back to the old way... Thus only the first fix of your link seems relevant, but it doesn't help me. An alternative solution would be to automate the re-coupling procedure... But automating devices and bluetooth detection doesn't look that easy. :-(

Comment: @TomWij: Method 4 or an adaptation of it goes into most relevant bluetooth windows and it would be nice to know what they all say. Method 6 asks a very pertinent question: Did you test this mouse on another computer?

Comment: @harrymc: As stated, that detailed window said "Currently Connected", any other data there is really not relevant to this problem. Other computers here don't have bluetooth...

Comment: Okay, I decided that it's either the mouse that gets empty or it's my Windows that has a problem... As this boot, it worked just fine. In some weeks I'll get a SSD and thus do a reinstall, I'll hope for the problem (and other problems like not being able to use eSATA) to resolve itself...

Answer (score 2):

For me the thing that solved this issue was: in Windows Services find service "Bluetooth Support Service" and make sure it is in "Auto" launch mode and is started by "System" (first option without a textbox to enter user name). Source: [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/894035)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clicking the mouse and giving it a couple seconds to connect? Some mice will go to sleep and won't reconnect until "woken up".

Comment: Already tried, doesn't help... :-(

Answer (score 0):

If it says "Currently Connected" however the mouse is obviously not operational, then you have probably disabled "Allow Bluetooth devices to connect to this computer" in the properties of Microsoft Bluetooth Stack. It prevents newly attached devices - and not just newly paired devices - from connecting to Bluetooth host-level protocols, while the connection is established nonetheless at controller level.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem of it not seeing my headphones in the "Add a device" wizard.  I had to go to device manager, right click the bluetooth device, and enable it.  Not sure how it became disabled in the first place.